# Detect When A Node is Visible in a Scene

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to find a way to detect (or receive notification) that a Node has been added to a Scene and is visible.

I am creating Node objects off the main JavaFx thread and add them to the Stage and Scene using `Platform.runLater()`. However I would like the Node object to receive notification that is has been added to the Scene and is visible, for example I wish to trigger an animation to start.

I can't seem to find any property or method to add a listener to capture such an event. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third-party JavaFX library [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) has a mechanism for this, and this exact use case is cited in the [blog](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/val-a-better-observablevalue.html). In short, you can do

```
Val<Boolean> showing = Val.flatMap(node.sceneProperty(), Scene::windowProperty)
    .flatMap(Window::showingProperty);
```

and then of course

```
showing.addListener((obs, wasShowing, isNowShowing) -> {
    if (isNowShowing) {
        // node is showing
    } else {
        // node is not showing
    }
});
```

The standard library has a version of this, but it is very badly written. (It is not typesafe, has no compile-time checking that the properties exist, and also pipes a lot of unnecessary warnings to standard error if any of the properties in the "chain" are null, even though the API docs indicate this is a supported use case.) If you want to do this with the standard JavaFX library, you can do

```
BooleanBinding showing = Bindings.selectBoolean(node.sceneProperty(), "window", "showing");
```

and then use the binding the same way as above.

Finally, you could do all this by hand, but it gets a bit ugly to manage the listeners properly:

```
BooleanProperty showing = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

ChangeListener<Window> windowListener = (obs, oldWindow, newWindow) -> {
    showing.unbind();
    if (newWindow != null) {
        showing.bind(newWindow.showingProperty());
    } else {
        showing.set(false);
    }
};

ChangeListener sceneListener = (obs, oldScene, newScene) -> {
    showing.unbind();
    if (oldScene != null) {
        oldScene.windowProperty().removeListener(windowListener);
    }
    if (newScene == null) {
        showing.set(false);
    } else {
        newScene.windowProperty().addListener(windowListener);
        if (newScene.getWindow() == null) {
            showing.set(false);
        } else {
            showing.bind(newScene.getWindow().showingProperty());
        }
    }
};

node.sceneProperty().addListener(sceneListener);
if (node.getScene() == null) {
    showing.set(false);
} else {
    node.getScene().windowProperty().add(windowListener);
    if (node.getScene().getWindow() == null) {
        showing.set(false);
    } else {
        showing.bind(node.getScene().getWindow().showingProperty());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use your code after the `Finally, you could do all this by hand, but it gets a bit ugly to manage the listeners properly`. And I do `showing.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)->{ if (newValue) { TO DO WHEN NODE IS VISIBLE}});`. However, it seems to me, that I get this event, but node is not yet visible. Can it be true?

Comment: @Pavel_K Not as far as I am aware. You can post a question with a [MCVE].

Comment: This solution gives answer to a question - `How to detect when a node becomes a part of scene?`  but not to a question `How to detect when a node becomes visible`?

Comment: @Pavel_K No, that is not true. The `showing` property does not become true if the node is part of a scene unless the scene is part of a window and the window is showing, which is a reasonable description of "visible", and certainly one that works for the purposes of this question. From other things you have posted, you want to know "when have layout calculations been (or when are layout calculations being) performed"? That's, maybe, another reasonable definition of "visible", but for those purposes you should use proper layout techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to the children property of container node into which you are adding the new node.

```
grid.getChildren().addListener((ListChangeListener<? super Node>)  change -> {
   System.out.println(change.getList().get(0).getTypeSelector());
});
```

`change.getList().get(0)` returns the first node that is added to grid object.

After James's comment, I have looked up and yes, it is possible to do it from node's perspective as well. You can listen to parentProeprty's changes on the node. Following snippet shows the way to do it.

```
Button b = new Button("Test");
b.parentProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->        {
    System.out.println("added to a container " + newValue);
});

answerPane.getChildren().add(b);
```

Comment: Is there no notification/event from JavaFX itself to Nodes?

Comment: No change happens to a JavaFX nodes when they are added to a container

Comment: @Buddha The statement in the last comment is not true: nodes have a `parentProperty()` which will change when the node is added to a container. Additionally, the `sceneProperty()` may change.