# Get visible state of Node in JavaFX 8

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I need to detect if a node is currently displaying.
I.e. if my Node is in a TabPane, I need to know if it is in a selected tab or not.

In the example, I want to know when the HBox is displaying.The visibleProperty and managedProperty of Node, does not seem to help me:

```
public class VisibleTest extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    TabPane tabpane = new TabPane();
    tabpane.getTabs().add(new Tab("Tab1", new Label("Label1")));

    HBox hbox = new HBox(new Label("Label2"));
    hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: aquamarine;");

    hbox.visibleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println("Hbox visible changed. newValue: " + newValue);
    });

    hbox.managedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println("Hbox managed changed. newValue: " + newValue);
    });

    Tab tab2 = new Tab("tab2", hbox);
    tabpane.getTabs().add(tab2);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tabpane));
    primaryStage.setWidth(600);
    primaryStage.setHeight(500);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

I know, it is possible to listen on the `selectedProperty` state of the tab, but this does not solve my real problem.

`Node.impl_isTreeVisible()` does what I want, but this is depricated API.

Any ideas? 
------------------------------------ update--------------------
I realize the code example above does not explain well what I'm trying to accomplish.
 Below is some Swing code that kind of demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish in JavaFX. Detect if the JComponent/Node is visible/shown, and based on that state, start or stop background processes. How would the constructor look like if it was a javaFX class.

```
public class SwingVisible extends JComponent {

    String instanceNR;
    Thread instanceThread;
    boolean doExpensiveStuff = false;

    public SwingVisible(String instanceNR) {
        this.instanceNR = instanceNR;
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(new JLabel(instanceNR));

        instanceThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (doExpensiveStuff) {
                        /*
                         * do expensive stuff.
                         */
                        System.out.println(instanceNR + " is visible " + isVisible());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        /*
         * How to do this in FX?
         */
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                if (!instanceThread.isAlive()) {
                    instanceThread.start();
                }
                doExpensiveStuff = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
                doExpensiveStuff = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        /*
         * This block represents code that is external to my library. End user
         * can put instances of SwingVisible in JTabbedPanes, JFrames, JWindows,
         * or other JComponents. How many instances there will bee is not in my
         * control.
         */
        JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        jtp.add("tab1", new SwingVisible("1"));
        jtp.add("tab2", new SwingVisible("2"));
        jtp.add("tab3", new SwingVisible("3"));

        JFrame f = new JFrame("test");
        f.setContentPane(jtp);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Output when tab1 is selected:

> 1 is visible true
>      1 is visible true
>      1 is visible true
>      ...

Output when tab2 is selected:

> 2 is visible true
>      2 is visible true
>      2 is visible true
>      ...

Comment: Wouldn't you know that the hbox is displaying if tab2 is displaying?

Comment: No. If you run the code `hbox.visibleProperty()` or `hbox.managedProperty()` is never called. If you add a check for `hbox.isVisible`, it will always be true even if tab1 is selected.

Comment: That maybe true, but if you use my original answer you know the hbox is displaying/visible on the screen when tab2 is selected.

Comment: This code: `tab2.getContent().isVisible();`  It always return true.

Comment: The visibility of the `HBox` is equivalent to the selected property of the tab it is in, why not use that?

Comment: Because the code above is only to demonstrate the problem. And the problem is: How do I know if a 'Node' is visible or not.

Comment: You can control the visible state property and set it to false when the tab is not selected and true when the tab is selected. That way it will return false in the cases you need it to.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042212/detect-when-a-node-is-visible-in-a-scene) too.

Comment: The nodes are always visible even is you can't see them. They are just behind other nodes.

Comment: Read the Javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#isVisible--).

Comment: The correct approach to this is to use the `selectedProperty()` of the tab. The problem with any other approach is that it relies on the implementation of the tab pane. Currently, the tab pane works by laying out the content of all tabs in a single pane, and making the content of each visible or not visible according to whether the tab is selected or not. However, there is no guarantee that this implementation will remain in future releases: so your only option is to respond to the tab's selected property.

Comment: You said that "this is not the real problem". We do appreciate your effort in making a minimal, complete example, but it seems that it doesn't quite describe the problem you are trying to solve. See if you can figure out an example that does describe the actual issue. Note that knowing "when is a label visible" is extremely difficult, because you would really need to know if it, and all its ancestors, are visible, if it is part of a scene that is displayed in a window that is showing, and if there are any other nodes displayed over the top of it.

Comment: ' it seems that it doesn't quite describe the problem you are trying to solve' I'm starting to realize that...

Comment: BTW (and maybe you already know this, but it was just for demo purposes): there is no guarantee your Swing code will work as you want it to. You are accessing the `doExpensiveStuff` variable from two different threads without making any guarantees that changes made in one thread will be visible in the other thread. (So the background thread may continue for an indefinite amount of time after the component is hidden, and may never actually stop.) You need, at a minimum, to make `doExpensiveStuff` volatile.

Comment: Anyway, AFAIK there is no direct equivalent of the `componentShown` and `componentHidden` events in JavaFX. To establish the (closest) equivalent functionality, you would expose methods to start and stop the background thread from the control/node subclass, and invoke them from a listener on the tab's selected property (basically exactly as in the answers provided). In general, though, I would probably reconsider this design entirely. Background processes really should be services that are referenced from a controller or a model: they shouldn't really live directly in the view.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Tab`'s [`selectedProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#selectedProperty) to know if it is selected or not, and by extension if its content is visible or not. It is a boolean property.

I've converted your Swing code to JavaFX based on your initial JavaFX example:

```
public class VisibleTest extends Application {

    public class FXVisible extends Tab {

        FXVisible(String id) {
            super(id, new Label(id));

            Timeline thread = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> { 
                        if (isSelected()) {
                            // do expensive stuff
                            System.out.println(id + " is visible");
                        }
                    }),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1))
            );
            thread.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

            selectedProperty().addListener((selectedProperty, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
                if (isSelected) {
                    if (thread.getStatus() != Status.RUNNING) {
                        System.out.println(id + " starting thread");
                        thread.play();
                    }
                }
                // else, it is not selected -> content not shown
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TabPane tabpane = new TabPane();
        tabpane.getTabs().add(new FXVisible("1"));
        tabpane.getTabs().add(new FXVisible("2"));
        tabpane.getTabs().add(new FXVisible("3"));
        // add as many as you want

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tabpane));
        primaryStage.setWidth(600);
        primaryStage.setHeight(500);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I replaced your thread with a JavaFX [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/animation/Timeline.html). Your question is not about this topic so I won't go into details here, though it's self explanatory.

I don't understand why in the Swing example you have a listener changing a boolean that indicates if the component is visible or not when you can just call `isVisible()` directly in the thread (see comments below for a note about threading). This is why in my code above I took the approach of checking `isSelected()` directly with no self-declared boolean. If you need to revert to your design it's rather straightforward. Just noting this for clarity.

The `ComponentListener` can be replaced with a change listener on `selectedProperty()` and querying the new value. Just be sure that your example does what it's supposed to do: the first time the tab is selected the thread/timer starts. After that the thread/timer does nothing. You might have wanted to pause the computation for non-displaying content. Again, just noting it because it seemed like a potential mistake to me, otherwise you're fine.

Comment: Threading comment: For the Swing code, `isVisible()` should only be called from the AWT event dispatch thread: it's not a thread-safe method. The `visible` property will be changed by the Swing framework on the AWT event dispatch thread: there is no guarantee as to when, or even if, other threads would "see" those changes. The code the OP posted is also flawed, but could be fixed by replacing the `doExpensiveStuff` boolean with an `AtomicBoolean`, or by marking it `volatile`.

Comment: @James_D Good point. I did some tests with a Swing Timer and `isVisible()` always updated correctly, though if what you say is true them some synchronization is required. Is it the same case with javaFX's `isSelected()`?

Comment: Yes, JavaFX is also single-threaded. (And, as I think you know, just because it happens to work correctly in tests is not the same as knowing it will always work correctly. Other platforms or JDK versions, or even just occasional unlucky timing, may cause things like this to break.)

Comment: @James_D Updated the answer to refer to the comments on the threading issue.

Comment: Thank you user1803551. I have tested your code. And tried to modify it. My problem is, that I still has to rely on the tab to do the notify my node of it's visible/shown state. The tab(or other type of parent) is external to my library.

Comment: @Olzen If you can just get a reference to the tab you could implement the solution, and you should be able to by traversing the parent graph upwards from your component. If not then you'd have to create a new MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer.

```
tab2.getContent().isVisible();
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!

Let me rephrase my question to be more specific: How does a Node know if it is currently displaying?

In Swing I can use Component.isVisible() or a ComponentListener to get this information. In JavaFX, isVisible behaves different.

Comment: In what way is Swing node.isVisible() different from JavaFx node.isVisible()?

Comment: In JavaFX it seems to be true, even if the Node is not displaying.

Comment: *"How does a node know if it is currently displaying"*: it doesn't. Layout and rendering are performed "top down". So the root of the scene lays out its controls, and renders itself by rendering the child nodes (or possibly parts of the child nodes) it calculates need to be rendered. Each child node, if it is a `Parent`, recursively does the same for its layout. So a node doesn't know if it is visible (in the sense that you mean) or not, it just gets told to to perform its own layout by its parent when necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So it is not possible for a Node itself to detect if it's showing/visible on screen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that my original answer is correct. If not, you need to ask your question in a better way. You want to know when the hbox is visible(meaning you can see the hbox on the screen).

```
tabpane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obsVal, oldTab, newTab)->{
    System.out.println(newTab.getText());
    if(newTab.getText().equals("tab2"))
    {
        //You can use this code to set the hbox visibility, that way you can force the behavior you are looking for.
        hbox.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("hbox is visible!");
    }
    else
    {
        //You can use this code to set the hbox visibility, that way you can force the behavior you are looking for.
        hbox.setVisible(false);
        System.out.println("hbox is not visible!");
    }            
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposal!

Answer (score 0):

From quick checking this seemed to work for both checking the window is showing and that the tab it is in is displaying. I have also checked and it seems to work as expected for titled panes too that are collapsible.

```
public static boolean detectVisible( Node node )
{
    Node current = node;
    while( current != null ) {
        if( !current.isVisible() ) {
            return false;
        }
        current = current.getParent();
    }
    Window window = Optional.of( node ).map( Node::getScene ).map( Scene::getWindow ).orElse( null );
    if( window == null ) {
        return false;
    }
    if( window instanceof Stage && ( (Stage) window ).isIconified() ) {
        return false;
    }
    return window.isShowing();
}
```