# Alternative for removed impl_isTreeVisible()

Tags: javafx, java-9

We are reliant on Node.impl_isTreeVisible() because isVisible does not work properly (or at least the way we want it to).

```
/**
 * @treatAsPrivate implementation detail
 * @deprecated This is an internal API that is not intended for use and will be removed in the next version
 */
@Deprecated
public final boolean impl_isTreeVisible() {
    return impl_treeVisibleProperty().get();
}
```

We have a custom Node which contains a Plot. This gets continuous data. We want to avoid to update the plot if it is not visible (still managed/rendered, but hidden).
If the node is placed on a tab which is not selected, hence it is not visible in the window, then using isVisible still returns true. This causes the Node on the selected tab to be rendred every time the plot is updated.

This will evaluate to true even though the node is not visible in the application window.

```
if (isVisible()) {
    updatePlot()
}
```

So we have been using the following which works as we want it.

```
if (impl_isTreeVisible()) {
    updatePlot()
}
```

However this will no longer work in Java 9 as such methods are removed. Is there a new approach to this in Java 9?

**Update**:
Looking at Java 9 source code for javafx.scene.Node I have found the method isTreeVisible(), which looks like a replacement for impl_isTreeVisible. However looking at the Javadoc I cannot find this isTreeVisible().
http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html

Trying with an example using isTreeVisible() will not compile with Java 9

```
Java9AppTest.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
                    if (text1.isTreeVisible()) {
                         ^
  symbol:   method isTreeVisible()
  location: variable text1 of type Text
```

**Update2**: Failed to see at first that isTreeVisible() is package private.

**Update3**: Taken another look at Node source code, I started to check out NodeHelper if could use it to get isTreeVisible(), however the package NodeHelper is not visible. Though using --add-exports for com.sun.javafx.scene to get access to NodeHelper works.

```
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Then I can read the state of isTreeVisible() of a Node.

```
final boolean isTreeVisible = NodeHelper.isTreeVisible(node);
```

**Code Example**

Contains two Tab, each with its own Text.
Has a Task that updates each Text.
Using isVisible() will update each text on both tabs.
Using impl_isTreeVisible() will only update the text that is truely visible.
It makes sense that Text should be updated, even if it is not visible. This is just to illustrate the problem. Replace Text with background process that does alot more CPU heavy work.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Java9AppTest extends Application {

    private Text text1, text2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Java9AppTest.launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TabPane root = new TabPane();

        VBox box1 = new VBox();
        text1 = new Text();
        text1.setText("Hello World!");
        text1.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue,     newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("text1 changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
        });
        box1.getChildren().addAll(text1);

        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
        tab1.setContent(box1);

        VBox box2 = new VBox();
        text2 = new Text();
        text2.setText("Another Hello World!");
        text2.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("text2 changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
        });
        box2.getChildren().add(text2);

        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2");
        tab2.setContent(box2);

        root.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see javafx.concurrent.Task#call()
             */
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                final String oldText = "Hello World!";
                final String newText = "New Hello World!";
                while (true) {
                    if (text1.isVisible()) {
                        if (text1.getText().equals(oldText)) {
                            text1.setText(newText);
                        } else {
                            text1.setText(oldText);
                        }
                    }

                    if (text2.isVisible()) {
                        if (text2.getText().equals(oldText)) {
                            text2.setText(newText);
                        } else {
                            text2.setText(oldText);
                        }
                    }

                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
            }

        };

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setWidth(200);
        stage.setHeight(200);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX 9 Application");
        stage.show();

        Thread thread = new Thread(task, "Task");
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no new approach for this in Java 9: in fact there isn't really an "old approach" for this in Java 8. The `@treatAsPrivate` comment is supposed to imply that you should treat this as a private method: i.e. it should not be called from a subclass. (Basically, the JavaFX team wanted to make this private, but couldn't do so without the implementation of project Jigsaw, which was delayed from Java 8 to 9.) The "replacement" for `public final boolean impl_isTreeVisible()` in Java 9 is the package-private `final boolean isTreeVisible()` method.

Comment: So basically, it just sounds like you are doing something in a way that is not intended at all. Can you post a simple example of where you think you need this? Typically, in the rare occasions I've needed a custom component, I subclass `Control` and write a skin that is a subclass of `SkinBase`, overriding `layoutChildren()`. AIUI, `layoutChildren()` will only be called when needed.

Comment: Updating our Plot which lies elsewhere. It might be placed on a Tab, or it might be hidden on a different Node. The point is it is hidden, but isVisible returns true. If we update this plot it will cause the nodes that are visisble to be rendered every time. Using isTreeVisible returns false if the Plot node is really not visible. Perhaps our implementation of the Plot is wrong since it causes all other Nodes elsewhere to be rendered when it is updated.

Comment: Yes, I understood all that. How are you actually implementing this? Can you provide a complete but simple example?

Comment: Looks like Java 9 does have isTreeVisible() from reading the source code, but it is not there in the Javadoc.

Comment: Because that method is package-private.

Comment: @James_D: Yes, you are right. I did not see at first that it is package private.

Comment: A question that is related to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43305573/1835477).

Comment: unrelated: you must not change any node in the scene off the fx-application thread .. weird that Text doesn't throw up (Label does)

Comment: you might consider raising a issue to move the isTreeVisible into public scope in the bug parade - use-case should be common enough - illegal-access will be removed in future versions (not sure when, planned was 10 but that was before the jdk release strategy changed to time-based, that is every half-year)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest adding a property to your node, that controls if you want to update the plot. So instead of `if (impl_isTreeVisible()) {` just have `if (shouldUpdate) {`. Upon tab selection changes, just toggle the property. So in essence your `TabPane` would control if the plot is updated.

Alternatively you could pass the `TabPane` to your node and query the selected tab: `tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()`. This, however means that your node must know on which tab it resides.

Comment: Not applicable. This hack could be possible, but the Node could either be on a Tab, or a Window which is minimized.

Answer (score -1):

- A [Tab](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#selectedProperty) has a property `selected`, bind that property to an `update` property of your plot, which determines if you redraw your plot.
- In your control (or its skin) add a listener to the `update` property of the plot, where you pause or resume listening to your input source, or pause or resume the timer that gets the data.

This solution does not add additional dependencies to the object graph, the type of container it should be in and enables you to create more complex bindings if necessary (like a pause button), and eases testing as this property is controllable in a standalone manner.

Depending on the data source implementation this solution can also pause your data source if it determines that there are no listeners processing your data actively.